# Python Discord on_member_join

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

Excuse me for my bad english :-)

I have a problem that a Discord bot I work on does not send private message to members after they join. I tried several solutions suggested in other Stack Overflow posts, but it doesn't work.

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'Someone joined')
    await member.send("You joined")

client.run("XXX")
```

But the function is never executed.
If I use the exact same code in a command like `?join`, as in the following example, it works!

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    print(f'Someone joined')
    await member.send("You joined")

client.run("XXX")
```

So am I wrong thinking that `on_member_join` doesn't work anymore? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time :-)

Answer (score 1):

As of discord.py version 1.5+, `Intents` for bucket types of events must be stated by the bot prior to use. The event `on_member_join` needs the intent of `discord.Intents.members` to be set to `True`.

An easy way to do this is the following:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)
```

`discord.py` version 1.5 states that if the intents are not specified, it allows all intents except for `Intents.members` and `Intents.presences`.

More information on Intents can be found here: [Gateway Intents in discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#)